# Non-squar kernel in java.awt.image.ConvolveOp

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics, 2d

I have sample image processing code which applies a convolution filter over an image using following kernel:

```
float kernel[] = {-1,0,1};
```

and the application of filter:

```
new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(1,3, kernel), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null).filter(copy, img);
```

I am wondering how ConvolveOp will behave, dealing with a non-square kernel matrix? I far as I know we must use a *square matrix* with *odd* number of rows in Convolution algorithm.

**PS.** I thought that it (java) may pad it with zeros (e.g. {0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0}) but I a more sophisticated case we can also have a kernel of this form with no run-time error:

```
    float data[] = {
        -1,0,1,
        -1,0,1,
        -1,0,1,
        -1,0,1
    };
```

which cannot be padded to become square with odd number of rows.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that says that a convolution kernel has to be a square matrix.

Comment: thank you Oli,You mean it will act as it is padded with zeros to become a square matrix?

Comment: Convolution doesn't require a square matrix; it's as simple as that.  So yes, it will act the same as a zero-padded matrix, but that's always true.

Comment: Oli, can you explain how in second example the matrix is applied. I mean which point is considered the center point?

Comment: @Bakhshi: As it says at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/Kernel.html, the origin is (width-1)/2, (height-1)/2.

Comment: thank you again. It seems that I was considering it more complicated than it is :P you helped me a lot man.